# CMake + MSBuild project shows repeated entries

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, msbuild, qt-creator

I have two projects previously built using CMake with "Visual Studio 12 2013" as the generator. Qt Creator manages to successfully parse both projects, but all source files and headers are duplicated in one of the projects and quadrupled in the other. Here's how it looks:

[image: Quadrupled main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt]

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? The CMake commands used to build those projects are nothing unlike the usual -- just `cmake .. <some flags>` then `cmake --build . --config Release`.

Comment: Organization of files in the IDE for VS project generators is done by setting properties.  Most likely your CMakeLists.txt does not set any of the properties to organize things.  It is a cosmetic issue only.  Take a look at the [FOLDER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/FOLDER.html) and [USE_FOLDERS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_gbl/USE_FOLDERS.html) properties

Comment: Can you provide any example of a project using those properties? Thanks

Comment: I tried setting those properties, but nothing seemed to change

Comment: Use `FOLDER`/`USE_FOLDERS` to organize targets and use [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) to organize source files within a target.

Answer (score 0):

CMake will generate several configurations with the msbuild generator. Creator will then report one file per CMake configuration.

There is a variable to tell cymbals which configuration to build and limit this down to one, but I do not know it's name on top of my head right now. There is a bug report open against Qt Creator for exactly the issue you describe, and that has this information:-)